# Using InputStreamEntity for buidling a http put request with httpclient won't work unless I pass the content length explicitely

Tags: java, scala, httpclient

I am trying to do a http request in scala using httpclient from org.apache.httpcomponents version 4.23. In particular I want to do a put using an InputStreamEntity to build the request in order to avoid copying over a large (~100Mb) byte array in memory. Here is the snippet:

```
val req = new HttpPut(url)
req setEntity new InputStreamEntity(contentStream, -1/*contentlength*/)
val client = new DefaultHttpClient(connManager, httpParams)
val resp = client execute req
```

In the code url, connManager, httpParams are defined elsewhere. The result of the code is the creation of a file on the desired location with NO content. I am testing with a contentStream which has 3 bytes. Creating the InputStreamEntity with content length as argument set explicitly to 3 will result in the code to create the file the right way. For good reasons in production I won't know the length of the stream hence I want to use negative numbers to make sure the entire stream is sent until, as advertized by the api of InputStreamEntity, the end of the stream is reached.
What am I doing wrong? Why am I getting an empty file when not explicitely setting the content length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not setting the content-length, will result in HTTP Client switching to [chunked transfer-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)

For this to work, the http server you are posting to must be HTTP 1.1 compliant. Is it ?

Comment: I am using lighttpd 1.4 and I just found out about this http://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/2156 open issue, so it doesn't  support Chunked Transfer Coding for HTTP PUT.